# Python: Remove repeated element when doing duplicates counting

Tags: python, for-loop, duplicates, tuples

Below is the tuple for 3D point group

```
f = [[10, 20, 0], 
    [40, 20, 30], 
    [20, 0, 30], 
    [10, 10, 0], 
    [30, 10, 10], 
    [20, 0, 30], 
    [20, 10, 20], 
    [10, 10, 0]]
```

Each point corresponds with a certain number (index) indicating the type of point (assumption)

```
ic=[1,2,3,2,1,3,2,3,1]
```

Hence, the previous tuple could be presented as

```
f = [[10, 20, 0, 1], 
    [40, 20, 30, 2], 
    [20, 0, 30, 3], 
    [10, 10, 0, 2], 
    [30, 10, 10, 1], 
    [20, 0, 30, 3], 
    [20, 10, 20, 2], 
    [10, 10, 0, 3],
    [20, 0, 30, 1]]
```

Here is my code:

```
def selectUnique(x):
    count = Counter((i[0], i[1], i[2]) for i in x)
    out = [i for i in x if count[(i[0], i[1], i[2])] == 1]
    return out

selectUnique(f)
```

The result I want to obtain is shown below:

Unique part:

```
index       point         equivalent points    index
  0      [10, 20, 0, 1]           1             [1]
  1      [40, 20, 30, 2]          1             [2]
  2      [20, 0, 30, 3]           3             [3,3,1]
  3      [10, 10, 0, 2]           2             [2,3]
  4      [30, 10, 10, 1]          1             [1]
  6      [20, 10, 20, 2]          1             [2]
```

Duplicate part:

```
index       point         Duplicate or not
  5      [20, 0, 30, 3]       duplicate
  7      [10, 10, 0, 3]       duplicate
  8      [20, 0, 30, 1]       duplicate
```

My code is intended to realize the function of picking the duplicated points out and also indicating its index in the list. In addition, I also need to realize function showing how many equivalent points in my unique part and also the index for these equivalent points.

However, my code doesn't work, how can I revise it?

Comment: What specifically does it do wrong?

Comment: What I need to do is counting the point, it occurs the duplicates when three values in the point all equal the previous one.

Comment: 'my code doesn't work' - what error does it produce, if any? I've tried it, and everything works fine, and you're getting the right result you want to obtain.

Comment: will a `set([tuple(i) for i in f])` solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
uniq = []
dup = []
count = 0
for i, j, k  in f:
    if not [f.index([i,j,k]),i,j,k] in uniq:
        uniq.append([count,i,j,k])
    else:
        dup.append([count,i,j,k,"duplicate"])
    count += 1
uniq.extend(dup)
print uniq

[[0, 10, 20, 0], [1, 40, 20, 30], [2, 20, 0, 30], [3, 10, 10, 0], [4, 30, 10, 10], [6, 20, 10, 20], [5, 20, 0, 30, 'duplicate'], [7, 10, 10, 0, 'duplicate']]

for j in (uniq):
    j.append(ic[j[0]])
print uniq


 [[0, 10, 20, 0, 1], [1, 40, 20, 30, 2], [2, 20, 0, 30, 3], [3, 10, 10, 0, 2], [4, 30, 10, 10, 1], [6, 20, 10, 20, 2], [5, 20, 0, 30, 'duplicate', 3], [7, 10, 10, 0, 'duplicate', 3]]
```

Comment: BTW, how can I realize the output in my updated post?

Comment: I want to take a deep study about the duplicates and index, how can I revise your code and obtain the result as shown in my updated post?

Comment: @PythonFun, I edited my answer, is that what you want?

Comment: When I run your code, it told me "List index out of range". BTW, I want the duplicates term could show "duplicates" element in each tuple.

Comment: I added different code, it adds  the value  of ic to the corresponding sublist.

Comment: Thanks, bro. You really give me a great help!

Comment: @PythonFun, you don't need enumerate in the last loop, I amended the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not mind an alternative solution ...

```
f=[tuple(x) for x in f]
set(f)
```

Comment: The OP wants a list of lists, this is a set of tuples.

Answer (score 1):

by checking `count[(i[0], i[1], i[2])] == 1]`, you have eliminated all items that had occurred more than once. You can just return the keys of counter instead to get the deduped version

```
def selectUnique(x):
    count = Counter((i[0], i[1], i[2]) for i in x)
    return count.keys()
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. But how can I list them in the order and indicate their index?

Comment: @PythonFun, can you update your post to reflect the exact output you want?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: this answer matches the original specifications

Here's an alternative way:

```
def selectunique(lst):
    a = set()
    return [x for x in lst if tuple(x) not in a and not a.add(tuple(x))]
```

For

```
for point in selectunique(f):
    print(point)
```

the output is

```
[10, 20, 0]
[40, 20, 30]
[20, 0, 30]
[10, 10, 0]
[30, 10, 10]
[20, 10, 20]
```

Comment: Your answer is excellent. However, how can I indicate the index of these duplicates?

Comment: @PythonFun do you want the indexes as a return value built into the selectunique function or just do a test after you have aquired the list of unique points?

Comment: I want the indexes as a return value built into the selectunique function. Please refer to my updated output.

Comment: @PythonFun I see you have gotten good answers for your extended specifications in the meantime. My approach won't be so easy to adapt to the new specs without looking very ugly. Guess that's ok because you got your answer - cheers :)

Comment: I have change the form of f:                                   f = [[10, 20, 0, 1], 
    [40, 20, 30, 2], 
    [20, 0, 30, 3], 
    [10, 10, 0, 2], 
    [30, 10, 10, 1], 
    [20, 0, 30, 3], 
    [20, 10, 20, 2], 
    [10, 10, 0, 3]]

Comment: @PythonFun maybe it would be better to open a new question instead of changing the original post over and over :)